# Trying to link my "export default function" and it is coming up as undefined in my other react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to link one of my react components to the other and it is is coming up as undefined. I have no idea what to do now because I have no experience with linking an export default function.

I am trying to link this code

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  "pk_test_51IUqMCJ2iOysJZvP3vrQpEoV2l1SpF9PzkycqVdKjmC3RYuDC3AqTvRfBDcsDwDmtxJlkUyip4GQOb8Akt0lF3O100RSHVPfch"
);
const DonationButton = ({ itemID, amount }) => {
  const handleClick = async (event) => {
    const stripe = await stripePromise;
    stripe
      .redirectToCheckout({
        lineItems: [{ price: itemID, quantity: 1 }],
        mode: "payment",
        successUrl: window.location.protocol + "//localpdf.tech/merge",
        cancelUrl: window.location.protocol + "//localpdf.tech/merge",
        submitType: "donate",
      })
      .then(function (result) {
        if (result.error) {
          console.log(result);
        }
      });
  };
  return (
    <button
      onClick={handleClick}
    >
      Donate {amount}$
    </button>
  );
};
export default function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="justify-center items-center flex overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 z-50 outline-none focus:outline-none">
        <DonationButton
          amount={"5.00"}
          itemID="price_1IUx1FJ2iOysJZvP1LD3EzTR"
        ></DonationButton>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

To this component

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Navigation from "./Navigation";
import About from "./About";
import Contact from "./Contact";
import Portfolio from "./Portfolio";
import Resume from "./Resume";


function Header() {
  const [currentPage, handlePageChange] = useState("About");

  // The renderPage method uses a switch statement to render the appropriate current page
  const renderPage = () => {
    switch (currentPage) {
      case "About":
        return <About />;
      case "Portfolio":
        return <Portfolio />;
      case "Contact":
        return <Contact />;
      case "Resume":
        return <Resume />;

      default:
        return <About />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="navbar-brand">
          <a
            className="navbar-item"
            rel="noreferrer"
            target="_blank"
            href="https://github.com/Andrewy2416?tab=repositories"
          >
            <span className="content is-size-1 has-text-black">Andrew Yun</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </nav>
      {/* Pass the state value and the setter as props to NavTabs */}
      <Navigation
        currentPage={currentPage}
        handlePageChange={handlePageChange}
      />
      {/* Call the renderPage function passing in the currentPage */}
      <main>
        <div>{renderPage(currentPage)}</div>
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

At the top of the second code what do I put? do I put `import DonationButton from "./Donate.js"`

or do I put

```
import function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="justify-center items-center flex overflow-x-hidden overflow-y-auto fixed inset-0 z-50 outline-none focus:outline-none">
        <DonationButton
          amount={"5.00"}
          itemID="price_1IUx1FJ2iOysJZvP1LD3EzTR"
        ></DonationButton>
      </div>
    </>
  ); from ""./Donate"
```

THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR ANY HELP!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you've got a `Donate/` folder and within this folder, you've got an `index.js` file. If it's like that then on the `index.js` you should remove the `<App />` component a just export the `<DonationButton />` component as a default, such as:

```js
const DonationButton = ({ itemID, amount }) => {
    ...
};

export default DonationButton;
```

Then you can import it as `import DonationButton from './Donate'`.

Comment: Also, you should take into account relative paths when importing!

Comment: Thank you so much for the timely answer! That got it through

Comment: I'm glad that it worked!